# Bangla Font displaying issue in firefox 58 on ubuntu gnome 16.04

Tags: firefox, fonts

Anyone using firefox 58 on ubuntu gnome 16.04?
Last week I updated my firefox from version 57 to 58 and all of a sudden my bangla font support got messy in firefox. The bangla font rendering anywhere in the browser is scrambled. Anywhere means anywhere, the address bar, search bar, search box in google, writing box in facebook and in any other websites displaying bangla content.

I did not find any recent question about this, so asked anew.

The '্র'and the '্য' are not properly showing in the text.
Google chrome is working fine, libreoffice is properly displaying bangla fonts. So this seems not to be a system issue.
I checked by both disabling and enabling hardware acceleration, and that did nothing.

By inspect element method, I did see that the element is using my browsers selected font, but the rendering is not appropriate.

Anyone has any clue how this can be fixed?

Comment: Which font are you using? Are you using _Lohit Bengali_ provided by the `fonts-beng` package, or something else?

Comment: I have not set anything, but firefox set dejavu serif as default. I have unchecked the option of Allow pages to choose their own font for the sake of testing this issue.

Comment: DejaVu is not cabable of rendering Bangla, AFAIK. I'd suggest that you install the `fonts-beng` package and let us know if it makes a difference.

Comment: The firefox-locale-bn is installed. Are you suggesting any other package? I may be wrong in this, but in libreoffice, dejavu is properly rendering bangla.

Comment: `firefox-locale-bn` contains Bangla translations of menus and messages in the Firefox program, but that's unrelated to fonts rendering. And yes, I just suggested `fonts-beng`. ;)

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice. I just checked that fonts-beng and fonts-beng-extra both are already installed.

Comment: Can you please run the terminal command `fc-match -a | grep -i lohit` and let us know what it outputs by editing your question.

Comment: And one more thing, I just changed the default fonts for bangla inside firefox from dejavu to lohit, and the bengali fonts looks perfect, but the usual english webpages looks somewhat odd as it is also selected for Latin which is the default.

Comment: It seems that my primary problem is solved, should I edit the question and add the output or mark solved or something like that. This is my first question, so I dont know the formalities.

Comment: Ok, so it was something with the Firefox font settings. Good that you figured it out. Can you please post an answer below where you summarize the explanation/solution. (It's fine to answer your own question.) In a couple of days you will be able to mark it as the accepted answer to close this question and tell others that the problem was solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out by discussing it in the comment section. Thanks for the help.

It was a firefox font settings issue. Fonts-beng package and lohit bengali font were already installed in my system. If you do not have those, you should install those first. Then restart firefox, if it is not automatically detecting the correct font and bangla scripts looks broken, then you have to change the default font for bengali language in firefox from default to something known bengali font (“lohit bengali” preferred). It can be done by going to Menu > Edit > Preferences and in the General tab to the Language and Appearance section by clicking Advanced button, a pop up window will open showing Fonts for Latin (in default). You have to choose Bengali and choose one of the bengali font.

After this, click Ok and restart firefox. It should solve the problem.

I did not know if it was like this in the previous versions. I encountered this problem a few days ago just after the update from version 57 to 58, before that it was fine. They have fixed some font issues in the 58.0 build which is declared [here](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/58.0/releasenotes/?utm_source=firefox-browser&utm_medium=firefox-browser&utm_campaign=whatsnew). I think it has messed up some default settings which was automatically detected in previous versions. I may be wrong in this part, may be my system has done something to firefox, but it looks like the above mentioned process should solve this issue if it appears to others.

Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem, but now I see that all Bengali text are ok.(in DejaVu Serif)